# Android App theme is not changing when I press the system back button

Tags: android, themes

I know there are similar questions asked but I couldn't find a proper answer.

> Current Status of app

Right now I have implemented the two themes AMOLED / Day / System Default and everything is working fine.
To switch the theme of the app I am using the following command

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_RandomApp_Day);
```

> Problem

When I am switching the theme by the above command [settings.java], the theme changes normally and when I press the back arrow on the toolbar of the app [In app toolbar, not system back button], parent activity launches [MainActivity.java] and the theme of this activity is the one that I have set in settings activity. Till now the functionality is what is expected.

But when I perform the same task [changing the theme in settings.java] the theme in settings.java changes but this time with the **smartphones inbuilt back button** when pressed the theme in the MainActivity.java **does not change**.

Comment: Check both the back button are calling the `onBackPressed()` method or not?

Comment: Hey thanks for the help it solved the problem

Comment: Cool @koshur, Please upvote the comment if it works

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem as [drjansari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3546909/drjansari) I used the following code

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(settings.this, MainActivity.class));
    }
```

And It worked but now I have another problem XD